# Total Order Relation on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having trouble with this problem:

Show that on $\mathbb{C}$ there is no total order relation $\preceq$ such that:

(i) $\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb{C},~~x\preceq y\Rightarrow x+z\preceq y+z$

(ii) $z\preceq 0,~~x\preceq y\Rightarrow xz\preceq yz$

Comment: I believe there was a typo in your original image, that statement (ii) should have read $0\preceq z$ instead, as that corresponds with our usual intuition of how orders should work using the real numbers as an example.  Remember that orders should be *anti-symmetric*.  I.e. if $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq x$, then they must be equal.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a total order relation would $ i<0$ or $i>0 $
Your contradiction will be shown that none of them can hold.

Comment: Sorry, Im not understanding. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: There are certain functions that keep the order of a set of numbers. Such as $ x^2 $ will keep the order in this case: $ 0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \rightarrow 0\leq x_1 ^2\leq x_2 ^2$